# Change canva draw color with a button Kotlin/AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, canvas

I am studying Kotlin as my second language and I have been having some troubles.
What I want to do :
My exercise is to **change the color of the balls on the screen when I click on a button**. The answer given by my professor is not sufficient and is not executing. I know that it would be easier if a could call the Balls.draw() method but I can not because the canvas is not explicitly defined. I have tried so many other codes but nothing changes.

There is all my files:

Activity_main.xml :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/vMain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.example.up2.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/vMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt :

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.util.*


class MainActivity : Activity(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var drawingView : DrawingView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        drawingView = findViewById<DrawingView>(R.id.vMain)
        drawingView.setWillNotDraw(false)
        drawingView.invalidate()
        btn.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    override fun onClick(v:View){
        when (v){
            btn -> {
                drawingView.b1.paint.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
                drawingView.b2.paint.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
                drawingView.b3.paint.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DrawingView.kt :

```
package com.example.up2

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.SurfaceView
import java.util.*

class DrawingView @JvmOverloads constructor (context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0): SurfaceView(context, attributes,defStyleAttr) {

    val backgroundPaint = Paint()
    val random = Random()
    val b1 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)
    val b2 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)
    val b3 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
            backgroundPaint.color = Color.WHITE
            canvas?.drawRect(0F, 0F, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), backgroundPaint)
            b1.draw(canvas)
            b2.draw(canvas)
            b3.draw(canvas)
        }
}
```

Balls.kt :

```
package com.example.up2

import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.graphics.RectF
import java.util.*

class Balls(x:Float, y: Float, val diametre : Float) {
    val random = Random()
    val paint = Paint()
    val r = RectF(x, y, x+diametre, y+diametre)
    val color = Color.argb(random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256))

    fun draw(canvas: Canvas?){
        paint.color = color
        canvas?.drawOval(r, paint)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that you set `drawingView.b1.paint.color` in your MainActivity, but in Balls.kt.draw() you set it back to `paint.color = color`
Then, you should invalidate() the view when you make changes to it.

Meanwhile I refactored your code a little bit, I post it below. The only change in activity_main.xml was that I deleted the Buttons onClick attribute.

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val drawingView = findViewById<DrawingView>(R.id.vMain).apply {
            setWillNotDraw(false)
            invalidate()
        }
        btn.setOnClickListener{
                drawingView.randomizeBallColors()
        }
    }
}

class DrawingView @JvmOverloads constructor (context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0): SurfaceView(context, attributes,defStyleAttr) {

    private val backgroundPaint = Paint()
    private val random = Random()
    private val b1 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)
    private val b2 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)
    private val b3 = Balls(random.nextFloat()*500, random.nextFloat()*1000, random.nextFloat()*500)

    fun randomizeBallColors()
    {
        b1.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
        b2.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
        b3.color = (Color.argb(Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256),Random().nextInt(256)))
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        backgroundPaint.color = Color.WHITE
        canvas?.drawRect(0F, 0F, width.toFloat(), height.toFloat(), backgroundPaint)
        b1.draw(canvas)
        b2.draw(canvas)
        b3.draw(canvas)
    }
}

class Balls(x:Float, y: Float, diametre : Float) {
    private val random = Random()
    private val paint = Paint()
    private val r = RectF(x, y, x+diametre, y+diametre)
    var color = Color.argb(random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256),random.nextInt(256))

    fun draw(canvas: Canvas?){
        paint.color = color
        canvas?.drawOval(r, paint)
    }
}
```

Comment: @BrennoFerreira You're welcome! You can mark the answer accepted if it helped you. Thanks!